# Unity/C# null reference exception isn't present, but should be

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, null, nullreferenceexception

Program falls into this branch and still there is no crush, which is very unexpected. Object is destroyed and null, however all the data is still the same. For my understanding it should crush with null reference exception. Am I missing some general info about how null works in c# or i ecnountered some known bug in unity/dotnet?

```
if (begining == null)
{
    print(begining.marked);
    foreach (var near in begining.nears)
    {
        print(near);
    }
    print(begining!.distance);
    print(begining.nears_amount);
    print(begining.prev);
}
```

beggining is object of type Node:

```cs
public class Node : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int nears_amount = 3;
    public readonly HashSet<Node> nears = new HashSet<Node>();
    public float distance = Single.PositiveInfinity;
    public Node? prev = null;
    public bool marked = false;
    public void connect(Node another);
    private void OnDrawGizmos();
    public void disconnect_all();
    private void OnMouseOver();
    public static bool BFS(Node start, Node seeked);
    public static List<Node> Dijkstra(Node start, int depth = -1);
    public static List<Node> DFS(Node current, int depth);
}
```

debugger:
[image]

Comment: and where exacty do you expect an exception? And how did you examine an "object is destroyed and null"? Please show the code that "destroys" your object.

Comment: Also be aware that, yes, Unity does weird stuff with [null and MonoBehaviours](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html). Have you tried using the debugger? Also, have you set it explicitly to null, or do you just assume it should be null, because you called "Destroy()"?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the `if` statement suggests that the value of the object is indeed null (if it enters the the inner block); however, given that all of the values within that class have a default value (and seemingly no constructor to instantiate that class, I suspect that that is where his confusion is coming from

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Not that. If object is indeed null, you can't find what type of class it's refering too. And also, printed values are not default.

Comment: @MaxPlay I assumed. But it went to this brunch, and it should be null. I added debugging result to the post. 
Seems like null comparasion is overrided and it actually checks if the object is destroyed. But why only unity-related stuff is deleted, but not Node itselft? Would it be deleted with garbage collector later? Very weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: In general for things inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object` rather use the [`bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) when checking for existence

```
if (begining)
{
    print(begining.marked);
    foreach (var near in begining.nears)
    {
        print(near);
    }
    print(begining.distance);
    print(begining.nears_amount);
    print(begining.prev);
}
```

---

Note that Unity has a [Custom `==` implementation](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/de40e0701203950f5730812260d9be3946a8427d/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs#L390) ([see also further explanation here](https://blog.unity.com/technology/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it)) for anything inheriting from `UnityEngine.Object`.

This custom `==` is basically be based on

> ```
> static bool CompareBaseObjects(UnityEngine.Object lhs, UnityEngine.Object rhs)
> {
>     bool lhsNull = ((object)lhs) == null;
>     bool rhsNull = ((object)rhs) == null;
>
>     if (rhsNull && lhsNull) return true;
>
>     if (rhsNull) return !IsNativeObjectAlive(lhs);
>     if (lhsNull) return !IsNativeObjectAlive(rhs);
>
>     return lhs.m_InstanceID == rhs.m_InstanceID;
> }
> ```

While the underlying `System.Object` (= `object`) might actually **not** be `null` on the `c#` layer, this custom `==` additionally checks if the underlying instance on the `c++` layer exists or was destroyed (`IsNativeObjectAlive`).

Note how Unity doesn't show `NullReferenceException` but rather a custom `MissingReferenceException` indicating that this `System.Object` is actually not really `null` but it is rather the Unity operator `==` that returns `true` for `null`, even if the `System.Object` still exists.

This happens as soon as you destroyed an object and then try to access it in the same frame (or better said before GC collects that instance and makes this `System.Object` actually `null`).

So in general: Do not use `== null` but rather the `bool` operator for checking for existence (even though the Unity API often uses `== null` themselves unfortunately).

Even further: Also **never** use [`?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), [`??` / `??=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) or [`!.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) operators for `UnityEngine.Objetc` since they operate on the underlying `System.Object` as well and ignore the custom `==` and `Equals` implementation of `UnityEngine.Object`!